# Passing data from a Table View Controller to a Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass an image from my TableViewController to a DetailViewController. My problem is a logic problem i guess because Xcode doesn't show any error in my code. When i tap on any row and takes me to the DetailView, the DetailView shows nothing and i want the DetailView to show me the image i am passing.

**My TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomCellControllerCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *foodImgArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *foodTitleArray;

@end
```

**My TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.foodTitleArray = @[@"manito",
                           @"jatito",
                           @"dolorsito",
                           @"pajarito",
                           @"calalito",
                           @"chinguito"];

   self.foodImgArray = @[@"ajigallina.jpg",
                         @"anticucho.jpg",
                         @"causaRellena.jpg",
                         @"anticucho.jpg",
                         @"anticucho.jpg",
                         @"anticucho.jpg"];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {

       DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

       dvc.passedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.foodImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }    
}
```

**My DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *detailImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *passedImage;

@end
```

**And my DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.detailImage.image = self.passedImage.image;
}
```

Comment: Move this code `self.detailImage.image = self.passedImage.image;` to `viewWillAppear` method

Comment: why dont you just pass a image(like-- dvc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.foodImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];) and set that image to detailImage in DetailViewController (like-- self.detailImage.image = self.image).  try to put some break point to check if image in not nil in  DetailViewController.

Comment: @MidhunMP I just did and nothing happens

Comment: @pawan It worked! :O!! Why?? Removing the .image property?? :O!

Comment: @ketokun because, you were trying to pass a image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you just pass a image
like--

`dvc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.foodImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

and set that image to detailImage in DetailViewController like--

`self.detailImage.image = self.image`

try to put some break point to check if image in not nil in DetailViewController.